Cannot pair new device - Intel Wireless Bluetooth
I bought a MX Anywhere 3S to take with me when travelling.
Its working as one would expect a mouse to work with my private ThinkBook laptop.
However, on the business laptop that I use more, it won't pair no matter what I do:
This ThinkPad P1G4 uses the Intel Wireless Bluetooth.
The swift connection recognizes the mouse, but when clicking connect, nothing happens.

What I tried:

Reinstalling drivers from lenovo website
Installing latest drivers from intels website
Pairing using the add device dialog (dialog freezes)
Ran DISM and SFC

Strangely, my other paired bluetooth devices still connect and work. But I want to pair the new mouse.. Any ideas?
NOTE: I don't want to reset or reinstall windows.

https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023358393-Logitech-Bluetooth-device-doesn-t-connect-with-computer-tablet-or-phone

that wasnt any help; my MX master 3s is working fine on the laptop im trying to pair the new mouse with, so not outdated bluetooth. and i know about the pairing button..

Are you using the Logi Options+ software ?

What does the Event-log show after the program freezes?

The mouse seems to come with a USB receiver. Does that work?

Yes the usb receiver (not included) works. Bluetooth does too, just not on that P1G4 laptop.
And yes I have Options+ software installed.

With the USB receiver does it work on the P1G4 laptop, meaning that only Bluetooth has a problem?

Don't know if this helps: I once damaged the wireless antenna of my desktop. It caused my desktop to unable to pair with any new bluetooth devices. However, I could still use previously paired devices with a little lag. Replacing the antenna solved the problem.

i cant confirm a hardware problem. yes only bluetooth has the problem, and only on that laptop. my other bluetooth mice work fine with it.
